# How to parse yaml and get value for interface- deep structue

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to parse this yaml and I want to get the `values` of the `run` entry (test1 or test2) without success, here is my working example.

im a bit get lost with the map inside map :( ,
this is given yaml which I couldent change ...

any idea how could I got those values

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var runContent = []byte(`
version: "3.2"

run-parameters:
  before:
    run-parameters:
      run: test1

  after:
    run-parameters:
      run: test2

`)

type FTD struct {
    Version     string     `yaml:"version,omitempty"`
    BuildParams *RunParams `yaml:"run-parameters,omitempty"`
}

type RunParams struct {
    BeforeExec map[string]interface{} `yaml:"before,omitempty"`
    AfterExec map[string]interface{} `yaml:"after,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    runners := &FTD{}
    // parse mta yaml
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(runContent, runners)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error : %v", err)
    }
    for k, v := range runners.BuildParams.BeforeExec {
        fmt.Println(k, v.(interface{}))
    }
}
```

This is working example
https://play.golang.org/p/qTqUJy3md0c

also I've tried with

this is working

```
run := runners.BuildParams.BeforeExec["run-parameters"].(map[interface{}]interface{})["run"]
     fmt.Println("run: ", run)
```

what I've tried is this which works but what happens if the `run` value is empty or no entry at all,**this will cause a dump**  how can I overcome this ?

Comment: Duplicate. You must type assert the interface{} to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I've tried is this which works but what happens if the run value is empty or no entry at all,this will cause a dump how can I overcome this ?

You can do

```
runParams, ok := runners.BuildParams.BeforeExec["run-parameters"]

if !ok {
    // handle lack of "run-parameters" in BeforeExec
}

runParamsMap, ok := runParams.(map[interface{}]interface{})

if !ok {
    // handle "run-parameters" not being a map
}

run, ok := runParamsMap["run"]

if !ok {
    // handle lack of "run" inside "run-parameters"
}

runStr, ok := run.(string)

if !ok {
    // handle "run" not being a string
}

fmt.Println("run: ", runStr)
```

This is quite verbose so you could use something like https://github.com/jmoiron/jsonq, where you can specify a "path" to the desired value nested inside several levels of maps. Despite the "json" in the name, this library works with map[string]interface{} and not json files. But note that the library you use for yaml unmarshalling results in `map[interface{}]interface{}` instead of `map[string]interface{}` and you will have to use a different one in order for it to work with jsonq.

```
run, err := jsonq.NewQuery(runners.BuildParams.BeforeExec).String("run-parameters", "run")

if err != nil {
    // handle all possible errors in one place
}

fmt.Println("run: ", run)
```